# Subscribing to multiple Transfer events of various ERC20s

Tags: erc-20, events

I need to suscribe to Transfer events of couple of different ERC20s in order to catch transfers to my contract. And here is the question: to catch all those events I need to create instance of each contract, can I do this using standard ERC20 abi for each of this contract or it has to be abi dedicated to exact erc20 smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the ABI of a standard ERC20, this should work well as long as the tokens really follow the standard, which is true in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested only in the standard ERC20 `Transfer` events, then even a subset of the ABI is sufficient. For example, if you implement it in Javascript, then you can simply use this:

```
const ABI =
[
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs":
        [
            {"indexed": true , "name": "from" , "type": "address"},
            {"indexed": true , "name": "to"   , "type": "address"},
            {"indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256"}
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    }
];

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, address);
contract.getPastEvents("Transfer", {fromBlock: ..., toBlock: ...}).then(events => {
    for (const event of events) {
        console.log(event.returnValues.from);
        console.log(event.returnValues.to);
        console.log(event.returnValues.value);
    }
});
```

You can also choose freely the input parameter names, i.e., replace `from`, `to` and `value` above.